# in my case i have to use 5 col-md for one row and another col-md needs to go next row without open row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in my case i have to use 5 col-md for one row and another col-md needs to go next row without open row.
i tried with nth:child and its not help for me please help me to fix this issue
Please click full page on snippet to better view

```css
.col-md:nth-child(5){
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">hi my name is</div>
            <div class="col-md">hi my name is</div>
            <div class="col-md">hi my name is</div>
            <div class="col-md">hi my name is</div>
            <div class="col-md">hi my name is</div>
            <div class="col-md">this is next row</div>
            <div class="col-md">this is next row</div>
            <div class="col-md">this is next row</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by set flex-basis to 20%.

```
.col-md {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  you  fixed my problem and save my project.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using seven containers. You need six. The next thing, you have to attach the correct class for the last container (100%). Which is `col-md-12`. You won't need any additional CSS. Everything you need is supported by Bootstrap. Please revisit the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) on how layouting works!

As an additional information `col-md` occupies as much space in width as is available (evenly distributed between all elements/containers in a row). 
The below example demonstrates how you can do that.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div style="background: red" class="col-md">
    hi my name is
   </div>
   <div style="background: red" class="col-md">
    hi my name is
   </div>
   <div style="background: red" class="col-md">
    hi my name is
   </div>
   <div style="background: red" class="col-md">
    hi my name is
   </div>
   <div style="background: red" class="col-md">
    hi my name is
   </div>
   <div style="background: green" class="col-md-12">
    this is next row
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: You can also do it like that without `col-md-12`.

```
    .col-md:nth-child(5){
        flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
```

To stretch the `col-md` at position 5 to 100%.

Comment: thanks for the answer.the problem is the i have to loop 15 times to col-md so i cant use col-md-12 in middle of the code. i am looking for css help

Comment: @Naveen007 Well actually you can. There might be a condition to determine when to insert the `col-md-12`. That's how it works and I don't suggest to work around a layout because of that missing condition. If you don't have a condition to determine `col-md-12` why not simply adding it after the number of iterations it is necessary? Nonetheless you can actually achieve that with `col-md-12` and I would suggest to do that in code instead of fixing it with CSS. If you don't have access to the code you can also set the width manually to `100%` for the nth-child. That would the job as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  flex: 0 0 20%;  fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the wrap then control the `flex-basis`

```css
.col-md:nth-child(n + 6) {
  flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-wrap">
      <div class="col-md">
        hi my name is
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        hi my name is
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        hi my name is
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        hi my name is
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        hi my name is
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        this is next row
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        this is next row
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        this is next row
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  flex: 0 0 20%;  fixed my problem